# jQuery 1.7.1 - fadeout delay issues

Tags: jquery

I have this very simple jQuery script, which gives me error that delay is not a function.

What am I doing wrong? Thing is that everything works, except that delay is causing error :S

I made sure I'm loading only jquery library once, which is also latest version 1.7.1

```
function    statusInquiry(orderItemID)
{
    var loadUrl = "bl_updaInfo.php";

    $.post(  
        loadUrl,
        {"orderItemID": orderItemID, "type": "statusInquiry"},
        function(responseText){
            $("#reportArea" + orderItemID).fadeIn("slow").html(responseText);
        },
        "html"  
    );
    updateLogList(orderItemID);

    $("#reportArea" + orderItemID).delay(10000).fadeOut("slow");
}
```

ERROR I'm getting:
- `[19:44:10.792] $("#reportArea" + orderItemID).delay is not a function`

responseText is exactly this:

```
<table class="tablerainbow-noborder" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="color: #888786;" width="70%">Client requests status for this search.</td>
<td style="color: #888786;">Posted 2012-03-12 12:34:22 by Client</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to fade out in 10 secs or wait for 10 secs and then fade out?

Comment: You are passing in a string value.  Have you tried passing in a number (without the quotes)?.

Comment: @websymphony I'm trying to wait 10 seconds then fadeOut.

Comment: Also there is syntax error. Delay doesn't take string. Its should be delay(10000) in any case.

Comment: @Adrov, what is the output of `console.log($.fn.delay)`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `[19:47:11.575] undefined @ Web Console:1`

Comment: @Adrov, this looks like a library conflict at first glance, but `$.fn` would probably also be undefined in that case. It means something in your code is issuing `delete $.fn.delay;` or `$.fn.delay = undefined;`. Are you including external plugins? Can you reproduce the problem in a simple test case?

Comment: Did you try the answer from @KenRedler?  It looks like the `post` is causing jQuery to unload in the DOM perhaps.  Moving the animation calls onto the object in the callback for the `post` call might solve it.

Comment: @TLS Yes I've tryed that, but same issue.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Output of $.fn is fine I believe... It gives `[19:52:01.093] ({init:(function (E, H) {E = E || document;if (E.nodeType) {this[0] = E;this.length = 1;this.context = E;return this;}if (typeof E === "string") {var G = D.exec(E);if (G && (G[1] || !H)) {if (G[1]) {E = o.clean([G[1]], H);} else {var I = document.getElementById(G[3]);if (I && I.id != G[3]) {return o().find(E);}var F = o(I || []);F.context = document;F.selector = E;return F;}} else {return o(H).find(E);}} else {if (o.isFunction(E)) {return o(document).ready(E);}}if (E.selector && E`...

Comment: This one's tricky!  What is the full contents of `responseText` when you load the URL that you have?  If you are putting a complete page inside a `div` on an existing page, then you'll end up with conflicts.  You probably want just a portion of the response.

Comment: @TLS Response is table with 5 rows and in each row there is price, nothing special :S

Comment: @Adrov, your `$.fn` looks fine indeed. It really seems that `delay()` is selectively pruned for some reason. If you're using external plugins (code you didn't write), search for `delay` there to check if one of them is the culprit. Otherwise, their are only two possibilities left: either the jQuery script you're including is corrupted (clear your cache and change your script's origin, if possible), or the problem comes from your own code (you're not messing with `$.fn`, right?)

Comment: Would you mind adding the exact contents of `responseText` to your original post?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm using few other plugins, but i doubt they are issue. I think TLS is right, there is something wrong with that particular function, I've tested for last two hours and it seem that `.delay()` works just fine outside this `function    statusInquiry(orderItemID)`

Comment: I see that you've already accepted a good answer, but I was wondering if you've tried your original code *without* "html" as the `datatype` to the `post` method.  Perhaps that is forcing it to interpret what is technically an invalid HTML response (since it's only the table).  The default for that parameter is to allow jQuery to guess at the data type, so maybe it can figure it out on its own?  (If you'd rather just move on, that's fine - I'm just curious to know why the `post` call would cause trouble with the subsequent jQuery calls.)

Comment: @TLS I have not, how can I try that?

Comment: You can simply remove the "html" parameter and not pass any value.  The parameter is optional, so it can be omitted.  (Results may vary, but that's the whole point of this exercise.)

Comment: Tryed, still saying delay is not a function. I guess I just won't use delay then, because I can't make it work no matter what :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in a `string` value.  Have you tried passing in a number (without the quotes)?

Also, are you sure you're using this the way it was intended?  According to the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), `delay` affects the *next* animation in the queue, not the ones that have already been executed.

Ultimately, the answer depends on what you want to do.  The `fadeOut` command will not be affected by the call to `delay` if `delay` appears after the `fadeOut` in the call chain.  If you want to pause for a bit before the `fadeOut` occurs, then you'll need to switch the two calls around.

**EDIT**: More thoughts based on some interaction with @Adrov.

From the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for `post`, you might want to take a look at the contents of the `responseText` object when it goes into the `success` callback.  If you are putting a complete page of HTML into an existing `div` tag, you'll end up with conflicts and odd behaviors.  The example below is straight from the jQuery docs.  Notice how a `find` is executed on the results before putting the data into the existing page.

```
$.post( url, { s: term },
      function( data ) {
          var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
          $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
      }
    );
```

EDIT NOTE:  [Ken Redler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9672909/475820) suggests to chain the `delay` and `fadeOut` methods inside the `success` callback for the `post` method.  I just want to make sure that this suggestion doesn't get lost, as it's a very good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#reportArea" + orderItemID).delay(10000).fadeOut("slow");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `fadeIn` animation is in the success callback of an ajax call, you should move the `fadeOut` there as well. Otherwise your `fadeOut` will run (or try to run) before the element is shown.

So something like this:

```
function statusInquiry(orderItemID) {
  var loadUrl = "bl_updaInfo.php";

  $.post(  
    loadUrl,
    {"orderItemID": orderItemID, "type": "statusInquiry"},
    function(responseText){
      $("#reportArea" + orderItemID)
        .html(responseText) // makes more sense here, before animation functions
        .fadeIn("slow")
        .delay(10000) // pass a number, not a string
        .fadeOut("slow");
    },
    "html"  
  );

  updateLogList(orderItemID); // You might also want this in the success function
}
```

Comment: Good call moving all of the animations into the callback.  This saves lots of headaches with animation timing, as well as fixing the original problem.